# How to split jointly used iCloud account/Apple ID?

Tags: macos, accounts

My wife and I use the same apple ID but do not like cloud because we do not want each other's contacts or phone numbers. How do I take her off our joint ID, keep that one for myself, and set up her own apple ID for her phone and our shared IMac. She would sign on to the IMac using her own user account and not mine.

Comment: What exactly is an Apple account? Do you mean your Mac has one user account? Have you tried setting up her a new account in Users and Preferences to see how you can share programs but not data and settings? I would start with opening Finder and searching for "Add a second user account" in help and reading the **Create a new user account** help article to get started.

Comment: @bmike I believe by Apple account, he means Apple ID, as he references iCloud in his question.